# What is the name of a sequence structure where writes in the same area are faster?

Tags: data-structures, trees

I recall reading about a data structure for sequences where writes in the same area are faster due to some kind of caching or structure manipulation. What are some structures that do this? I know a gap buffer is one of them (kind of), but are there any others?

Comment: a B-tree is such a data structure, if I remember correctly

Comment: Also, are you talking about the spatial locality principle in caching?

Comment: @nirshahar I am talking more at the data structure level than the hardware level. Also, I am now realizing that this question may be more appropriate for cstheory.

Comment: A B-tree is totally a theoretical data structure. This site is for theory of computer science, so this question is totally appropriate here, at least in my opinion that is.

Comment: Linked lists???

Comment: @PålGD Linked lists are the opposite of that, since they are fragmented in the memory without using an entire "memory page" at once. So when you use linked lists, most likely you will have to do more calls to the RAM rather than some other data structure

Comment: @nirshahar but writes in the same area are faster

Comment: @PålGD and a Linked List is distributed into many areas, whilst a normal list is concentrated in a small amount of areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the data structure level, this is called a "finger". You might be looking for "finger search trees":

[https://cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/finger05.pdf](https://cs.au.dk/%7Egerth/papers/finger05.pdf)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for, thank you.